# Naming a function inside an Angular directive link necessary?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, hyperlink, directive

I'm doing the feedster exercise on Codecademy, having issues getting the button to work appear in the view, and it must be my syntax.

**Original code didn't work because named the function inline**

```
app.directive('plusOne',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/plusOne.html',
    link like(): function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.like = function(){
            element.toggleClass('btn-like');
        }; // internal function
    }; // link like function
  }; // return
}); // directive
```

Online searches just yield explanations of compilation and link theory. 
"" But is it necessary to name the function inline at the "link" level?

**Working code**

```
app.directive('plusOne',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/plusOne.html',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.like = function(){
                element.toggleClass('btn-like')
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Apparently this was just a wording issue for that question. It just requires an anonymous function.

Comment: there is no `like()` in link

Comment: `link: function(scope, element, attrs) { ...}`

Comment: Here are the directions for the exercise:    "Add a link option, and set it to this function named like():
function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.like = function() {
    element.toggleClass('btn-like');
  }
}"

Comment: Ok directions are perhaps semantically confusing. Therefore, is it true that you do not name "link functions"?

Comment: If you directives modify the DOM, they do so via link() function. One of the parameters of the link function is the scope. If your directive's template needs to talk to the directive itself, you simply attach functions to the scope on the directive and call it from the template.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to name that inline function is:

```
link: function like(scope, element, attrs) {
```

That being said, you can't really do anything with it at that point, you could/should consider using something like this to clearly define your linking function and directive definition separately:

```
app.directive('plusOne',function(){
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.like = function(){
            element.toggleClass('btn-like');
        }; // internal function
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/plusOne.html',
    link: link
  }; // return
}); // directive
```